# What is the measure of $\measuredangle AOC $ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference :In an ABC triangle:
H is orthocenter, I is incenter, and O is circumcenter of triangle ABC.
Calculates $\measuredangle AIC ~if~ \measuredangle AHC=\measuredangle AOC$

My draw:
[image]

[image]

I made it in two parts to improve the visualization

Comment: Hint: $O=H=I$...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  ..Yes, they are all worth $120^o$  but what is the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $\angle AHC = 180^\circ -  \angle B$ and $\angle AOC = 2 \angle B$

So, $\angle B = 60^\circ$

$\angle AIC = 180^\circ - \left(\frac{\angle A}{2} + \frac{\angle C}{2}\right) = 90^\circ + \frac{\angle B}{2} = 120^0$